# asp.net textbox enter time quantity

Tags: asp.net, time, format

I need a textbox in which user input a time duration, for example 43 hours and 10 minutes in the format 43:10 how can I do that?

This won't work:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDuration" TextMode="Time"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

TextMode property is available in asp.net 4.5 and above and this will be only recognized by latest browsers as this will be converted into HTML5 input tag.

```
<input name="txtTime" type="time">
```